# How to connect to European servers?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I've downloaded the mac wrapper for World of Tanks but I can only connect to US servers. Is there a way to force the client to connect to European servers?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think each installation is locked to a specific region, and the region you get depends on where you downloaded the client from. Did you download it from the European WoT website? If not, try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to download the wrapper from an European server but lost all progress I made on the US server.

Comment: yeah because servers are separate from each other.